# MongoDB not using my index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

I have a logs collection with millions of records. Creating a new index takes "forever". So it would be preferred to use existing indexes.

Now I want to get the number of occurances of certain error codes. I use this query, and functionally it works fine:

```
db.getCollection('logs.res').aggregate([
    {
       $match:{    
           timeStamp: {
               $gte: new Date('2017-05-01').getTime(), // timeStamp is Number
               $lt : new Date('2017-05-02').getTime()  // of ms since epoch
           },
           'objData.@.ErrorCode': {
               $ne: null
           }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$objData.@.ErrorCode',
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { count: -1}
    }
]);
```

The problem is that it takes well near 10 seconds just to execute this for a day. I had assumed the following index would be used: `timeStamp_-1_objData.@.ErrorCode_1`:

```
{
    "timeStamp" : -1,
    "objData.@.ErrorCode" : 1
}
```

However, MongoDB seems adamant to use some `timeStamp: 1` index (with some other indexes unrelated to the query), and scan alllllll the results to see if some responses might have an `ErrorCode` attached, even though this information should be in the index.

Here is the `explain()`:

[image]

- **Is there a way to use the** `timeStamp_-1_objData.@.ErrorCode_1` **index** to speed this up?
- **Why *isn't* it using this index?** I'm probably misunderstanding how indexes are used in this query.

---

Running MongoDB 3.2.7 on OSX.

**note:** I've also tried `$empty: true` in stead of `$ne: null`. It yields the same results, but some say you cannot use `$empty` if you want to use a compound index. Many questions on Stack Overflow are old (mongo 2.x) though.

Answer (score 2):

Winning plan is `CACHED PLAN`.
You can try clearing the cache plan.

```
db.getCollection('logs.res').getPlanCache().clear()
```

If after you clean the cache, Mongo is still using the wrong index. You can try setting the query plan or use "hint" to force your index

Comment: As far as I know, hinting is for testing purposes and you cannot set an index hint on an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: You can use planCacheSetFilter function before aggreggate

Answer (score 2):

Regular mongodb indexes use both field value and type to build the tree.

Queries like `$empty: true` or `$ne: null` don't have a parameter of any type and cannot benefit from such indexes. It is a special case, and requires a special [sparse index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/).

If your `timeStamp_-1_objData.@.ErrorCode_1` index is created as:

```
db.getCollection('logs.res').createIndex(
    {
        "timeStamp" : -1,
        "objData.@.ErrorCode" : 1
    },
    { sparse: true }
)
```

It should support your query best. Otherwise there is no much difference between `timeStamp_-1_objData.@.ErrorCode_1` and `timeStamp_1_module_1_etc` since the only first field is being used.

Comment: This might be relevant. So could I do `$nin: [array list of all error ids]` in stead? Or is a non-sparse index for a field that isn't always set pretty much useless?

Comment: Or better yet: `$ne: 999999`. This is a parameter of type number. It's just not used.

Comment: Yep, both should use the index, but it is not the same query as `$ne: null`.  You will get nulls in both cases. If you know all the error codes you can do `$in: [the list]`, but you may miss documents with unexpected error codes.